org.springframework.data.domain.Sort error sort represent string but store as number
I use spring data jpa and I implement sort using org.springframework.data.domain.Sort I have problem during sort some column ex invoiceNo it's represent string but It's value as number so when I sort 1-9 is work correct as normal but up to 10 when I sort desc 10 is smaller than 9.


Please consider adding code directly, instead of an image.

You cannot use expressions in the Order class only direction and the name of the property. If you want more complex sorting logic, use the criteria API and write the sort yourself or use queries.
